# How to automate a calendar

Tags: tikz-calendar

I have this calendar with tikz, and I want to make that it updates to the actual date, without doing it manually. Here is the calendar

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Can also use 11pt for a larger overall font size

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
  [
    dates=2022-11-01 to 2022-11-last,
    week list,inner sep=2pt,month label above centered,
    month text=\%mt \%y0
  ]
  if (at most=2022-11-30) [nodes={strike out,draw}]
  if (weekend)            [black!50,nodes={draw=none}]
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- `pgfcalendar` defines `\year`, `\month` and `\day` for the current year, month and day, that can be used

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Can also use 11pt for a larger overall font size

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
  [
    dates=\year-\month-01 to \year-\month-last,
    week list,inner sep=2pt,month label above centered,
    month text=\%mt \%y0
  ]
  if (at most=\year-\month-\day) [nodes={strike out,draw}]
  if (weekend)            [black!50,nodes={draw=none}]
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really usefull